# How to start a ZSH shell session with additional non-permanent aliases?

Tags: rabbitmq, pytest, zsh, nix, nixos

I'm using ZSH as my default shell on [NixOS](https://nixos.org/) I've added `rabbitmq-server` in a `shell.nix`, and need to pass the paths to its binaries to [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/) as command line arguments so the [pytest-rabbitmq](https://github.com/ClearcodeHQ/pytest-rabbitmq) plugin can find them.

For this, I'd like to be able to start ZSH with a `pytest` alias which includes the required parameters:

```hs
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> { } }:
(
  let rabbitmq_bin = "${builtins.toString pkgs.rabbitmq-server}/bin"; in
  pkgs.mkShell {
    buildInputs = [
      pkgs.python39Packages.pytest
      # ... (Python environment details omitted for brevity)
      pkgs.rabbitmq-server
    ];
    shellHook = "
      alias pytest=\"pytest \
        --rabbitmq-server ${rabbitmq_bin}/rabbitmq-server \
        --rabbitmq-ctl ${rabbitmq_bin}/rabbitmqctl\"
    ";
  }
)
```

I can add a `zsh` invocation in `shellHook`, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to instruct it to initialize the alias.

Solutions I've considered:

- Modifying [pytest.ini](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.0.x/reference/customize.html?highlight=pytest%20ini#pytest-ini). The file already exists in my project repository,
  and modifying it temporarily would make working with Git harder.
- Modifying [ZSH startup files](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files) in my home directory. A `pytest` alias would affect all my other environments as well. I could use a different alias name, but that would still remain in my static ZSH configuration polluting aliases.
- [buildFHSUserEnv](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#sec-fhs-environments). This is what I'm actually going to try instead if ZSH doesn't bend to my will.

Comment: Something like [this -- per directory ZSH config](https://coderwall.com/p/a3xreg/per-directory-zsh-config) might be useful, letting you add aliases only when you're actively in the project repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nix-shell`/`nix develop` were originally designed for the specific use case of debugging Nixpkgs stdenv-based builds, which use bash.

If you want to support a different shell, I'd [recommend](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/4609#issuecomment-1038967118) to create a custom shell launcher script that you can run with `nix run`. That gives you all the flexibility you need. That is, assuming you're ok with using experimental features.
Otherwise, you can create a script that fills the gap of `nix run`: running `nix-build` and `exec`-ing its result, which is your custom shell launcher.

Alternatively, you can generate a script to be `source`-d.

```hs
# zsh-functions.nix
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
let
  inherit (pkgs) lib;
in
pkgs.writeText "functions.zsh" ''
  PATH=${lib.makeBinPath [pkgs.hello]}:$PATH
  hi(){
    hello
  }
''
```

```
zsh% eval "source $(nix-build zsh-functions.nix)"
```

Comment: Your suggestion sounds reasonable. Unfortunately I don't have enough of an understanding of Nix to be able to follow the advice, but I'm marking this answer as accepted since you seem to know your stuff really well. Thanks!

Comment: I've added an alternative solution that's more composable, using `source` rather than starting a new zsh.